# Android Listview button doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, button, baseadapter

I created a custom listview with the base adapter, but for some reason can not click on the button inside the individual list views.

Here is the code the the main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Light List"
    android:id="@+id/lightName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/loginbutton"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lightName"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lightName" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lightList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lightName"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for views in the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lightList"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/lightName"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/statusText"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/buttonoff"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Lastly here is the adapter code:

```
public ArrayList<myLight> dataSet = new ArrayList<myLight>();

        public void makeLightList(ArrayList<myLight> lights) {
            Iterator<myLight> iter = lights.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                dataSet.add(iter.next());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dataSet.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lightlistlayout, null);

            TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lightName);
            name.setText(dataSet.get(position).name);

            TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
            if(dataSet.get(position).reachable) {
                if(dataSet.get(position).isOn) {
                    status.setText("Light is On");
                } else {
                    status.setText("Light is Off");
                }
            } else {
                status.setText("Light is currently not reachable");
            }

            dataHolder dh = new dataHolder();
            dh.name = dataSet.get(position).name;

            //Handle Off button click from list view
            Button offButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonoff);
            offButton.setTag(dh);
            offButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dataHolder dhv = new dataHolder();
                    dhv = (dataHolder)v.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), dhv.name + " Turned Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


            return v;
        }
    };
```

I am not sure if my onclicklistener is correct as I can't click on the button at all yet. Here is a picture showing the button. I have messed with different focus and clickable settings in the xml file and no luck. I added a seeker bar that I was able to slide that back and forth, but the button will not let me click it.[image: This Image shows how the buttons look different compared to the button on the bottom]

Comment: remove  `android:focusable="true"`

Comment: I just tried that, and triedcsettong it to false. Whilecdlimg searches prior to posting, most people has problems with selecting the row separate from a button. That is why I set it to true to make the button the focus, but that did not work. I am thinking I am missing something really simple somewhere, but have no idea what. Probably in the parent view, but as I mentioned in the question, when I had a seeker bar in the view I was able to select it, so I am really at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lightlistlayout, null);
```

Here you have inflated the row file for your adapter and the below are your id initialization and for that you have not added your view to your id, so try this.

```
TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lightName);
TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
Button offButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonoff);
```

Comment: I believe I did that in the getview for the adapter code.

Comment: Hmmm....if this answer helpful to you, kindly vote it, so more people will understand that this is actually working. Njoy and good luck.

Comment: I already did that in the original code and it does not appear to work. and other thoughts?

Comment: Hey, i thought you have added view holder twice in your code, it means inside the button click event you have added the same viewholder code, that will boy be needed for this.

Comment: For your reference, please see this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: And if you have to click in listvirw button object, you can add the same line below else part of your code and that works and if it is not working than let me know for this, dh.offButton.aetTag(position);

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
android:focusable="true" to android:focusable="false" in Button's xml
```